# DirectX 11 Getting description of Graphics Cards

Tags: c++, c++11, directx, directx-11

I am trying to iterate through the available GPUs on my system and print a description of each out onto the console. I have the code for retrieving them but I can't figure out how to get the description.

```
std::vector <IDXGIAdapter1*> availableAdapters = EnumerateAdapters();

for_each(availableAdapters.begin(), availableAdapters.end(), [](IDXGIAdapter1* adapter) {
    auto myAdapter = *adapter;
    auto adapterDescription = new DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1();
    myAdapter.GetDesc1(adapterDescription);
    // Print description to console here
});
```

I am getting a compile time error pointing to the `auto myAdapter = *adapter;` line though which says `error C2259: 'IDXGIAdapter1' : cannot instantiate abstract class`

I am using DirectX 11, Windows 64bit, and Visual Studio 2012. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
auto& myAdapter = *adapter;
auto adapterDescription = DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1();
myAdapter.GetDesc1(&adapterDescription);
```

Comment: Or simpler: `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 adapterDescription; adapter->GetDesc1(&adapterDescription);`